# How to avoid framer-motion layoutId animations to overlap with enter or exit animations

Tags: reactjs, animation, motion, framer-motion

My application (2 pages):

- **Page 1** contains a list of cards. Clicking on a card redirects to **Page 2** and triggers *layoutId* animations.
- **Page 2** contains the details of the list item. Clicking on overlay or back button redirects to **Page 1** and triggers both *layoutId* animations **AND** *enter* animation (both animations overlap - that's the issue).

[Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animatesharedlayout-app-store-demo-forked-s6dpt?file=/src/List.js)

I would like to know if it was possible to have a better control with the different types of framer-motion animations.

I would like to keep the *enter* animation when I arrive on **Page 1** except if there is a *layoutId* animation (For example, when I go to Page 1 from Page 2, I don't want the *enter* animation to overlap with *layoutId* animation).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.